# Firebase child_added

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have my app working now, but I'm not sure why it works...

I had some code similar to this:

```
var itemRef;

listRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildName) {
    itemRef = childSnapshot;
});
```

The problem was that when I tried to use `itemRef` later it did not work. It took me a couple hours to realize that the reference was not working, however, because `itemRef.name()` returned the correct name of the reference.

While searching the API, I came across the `.ref()` function. The API states that `.ref()` returns "The Firebase reference for the location that generated this DataSnapshot". This made the function sound completely pointless to me, but I decided to try it:

```
var itemRef;

listRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildName) {
    itemRef = childSnapshot.ref();
});
```

Can anyone explain to me why `.ref()` made my reference work when all it does is return "The Firebase reference for the location that generated this DataSnapshot." ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase exposes two distinct types of objects: [Firebase references](http://www.firebase.com/docs/firebase.html) and [DataSnapshots](http://www.firebase.com/docs/datasnapshot.html).

A Firebase reference is like a path.  It just points to a location in Firebase.  You use it to set() data, attach event callbacks using on(), etc..

A DataSnapshot stores data retrieved from Firebase at some point in time.  It only contains data.  You can call .child(), .val(), etc. to read the data, but you can't use it to do a set() or any other Firebase operations.

So your first code snippet doesn't work because it's storing the snapshot, which is different from a Firebase reference.  It just so happens that both objects have a .name() function which behaves identically, which may have caused confusion here.

Comment: Ah ok, so a DataSnapshot is essentially read-only I guess...
Thanks, very well explained as always. I love Firebase from what I've seen of it so far. Keep up the good work!